# Make textbox and image bring up datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I currently have this script which gives me an image next to the textbox.  If I click the image, it shows the datepicker:

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "+0:+1",
    showButtonPanel: false,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "image.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    onClose: function() {

        selectedDateTime($("#txtDate").val(), $("#ddlHourTime").val(), $("#ddlMinuteTime").val());

    }
});
```

How do I change this so the date picker displays itself if the textbox or the image is clicked.  At the moment, nothing happens when I click in the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is how you set up [showOn](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn). It is set to "button" so it will only open the datepicker when its clicked. Change it to "both" and it will open on both text box click abe button click.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Q697/1/)

```
$("#txtDateBoth").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "+0:+1",
    showButtonPanel: false,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "image.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
});
```